# Skip errors during QGIS batch processing

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, batch

Is there an option to skip any files which result in an error when batch processing in QGIS? I'm attempting to batch process about 100 shapefiles, some of which have null geometries. Processing stops as soon as processing reaches the first bad file. Can I set it to skip these files? Ideally I'd like to be able to see which files were skipped, but this isn't essential.

Comment: Which QGIS version? Try with 3.0.1

Comment: I've just installed it, but will need to transfer the files before I can run any processing tools. Does 3.0.1 skip null geometry layers by default?

Comment: Ndawson - I've just tried it in QGIS V 3.0.1 - changed processing settings to skip null geometries and it worked! Can you pop this in as an answer? Thanks :)